# How to update a model dynamically through checkbox inputs and render map changes immediately

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, model, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to have a collection of checkboxes tied to my `Site` model, and when the user checkmarks one, the associated location shows up on the map.

I've seeded my db with some sites in the following format:

**/db/migrate/seeds.rb**

```
Site.create(name: "Site name",
    latitude: 40.36618,
    longitude: -105.56095,
    include: false, )
```

I need the checkboxes I generate to update the `:include` field and then immediately show the new map markers as they are added.

**/views/sites/map.html.erb**

```
<div class="float-left">
<div class="inner-left">
  <%= hidden_field_tag("sites[]", nil) %>
  <% Site.all.each do |p| %>
    <%= check_box_tag("sites[]", p.name, p.include, { id: dom_id(p) } ) %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(p), p.name %>
    <br>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>

<div class="float-right">
<div class="inner-right">
  <div id="usmap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; position: relative;">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clear-floated"></div>

<script>
    var mymap = L.map('usmap', {
        ... 
        ... map parameters here...
        ...
    });

    L.marker([40.366,-105.56]).addTo(mymap)     // This is where I want to add/sub the markers for the 
                                                // map when a checkbox is checked/unchecked.
                                                // Need to loop through or just add/sub the new marker
</script>
```

The checkboxes show up and the map shows up with a single marker (that I hardcoded, shown above), so that's all good. Just really lost in the best way to proceed.

Comment: Attach an `onchange` handler to the checkboxes from Javascript. In there, send an AJAX request to the server to update the record. It can also remove the marker from the page immediately.

Comment: I would just avoid the whole `js.erb` and inline script tag mess. You're just going to be running around in circles and making the server way to involved in the state of the client. Instead just create a controller that serves up JSON, a view that contains the skeleton HTML needed and *real javascript* in your assets pipeline that fetch JSON data via ajax and use it to populate the map. I have a somewhat dilapidated hobby project that you can use as an example https://github.com/maxcal/remote-wind.